# How to create a definition shown on the picture?

Tags: floats, packages

I need to copy (with small editions) the shown definition in my own document. I don't have the source code of this pdf, so I don't have any idea which environment/package/etc. should be used to create the definition in same style.

[image: An example of the desired style]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Are the three titles "Given", "Find" and "Performance" constanst (i.e., will they appear in every instance of the description structure)?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes, they are. But in my case it is irrelevant, since i need this structure just in one place in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \begin{document}
   \noindent
   \hrule
   \begin{description}[nosep]
     \item[Given:] \null\leavevmode
        \begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=2ex,label=\textbf{---}]
          \item Give some thing
        \end{itemize}
     \item[Find:] \null\leavevmode
        \begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=2ex,label=\textbf{---}]
          \item Find some thing
        \end{itemize}
     \item[Performance measures:] \null\leavevmode
        \begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=2ex,label=\textbf{---}]
          \item How is it?
        \end{itemize}
   \end{description}
   \hrule
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for the inner lists (defined through two customized lists `esdescription` and `esitemize`) and [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) for the ruled frame; the advantage with this approach is that the rules enclosing the construct won't detach from the contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtcolorbox{esdefinition}{
  breakable,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colback=white,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  }
\newlist{esitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[esitemize,1]{itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt,label=\textbf{---},before=\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}  

\newlist{esdescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[esdescription,1]{style=nextline}

 \begin{document}

\begin{esdefinition}
\begin{esdescription}
\item[Given:]
\begin{esitemize}
  \item Give some thing
\end{esitemize}
\item[Find:] 
\begin{esitemize}  \item Find some thing
\end{esitemize}
\item[Performance measures:]
\begin{esitemize}
  \item How is it?
\end{esitemize}
\end{esdescription}
\end{esdefinition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if the final item has no descenders, as this one does, the rule at the bottom will always be closer than it should.  it should be possible to test for that, and adjust if necessary.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hmmm... that's weird. I am at work now and just tested my example code and the result was different than the one in the image (obtained at home with newer `tcolorbox` version): in the image, as you mention, the lower rule seems to be closer to the text but in my test at work, the two rules seem to be equally separated (I'll have a closer look at this later).

Comment: oh, joy.  probably a version discrepancy.  they are so annoying!